# Degeneracy of Atomic energy levels

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, quantum-spin, spectroscopy, interactions

I've started reading about the atomic spectra and came across LS coupling and so on. However, I have a doubt regarding the entire thing.

Let us say, we have 2 electrons, say $4p-4d$ state, and we are trying to find all the energy levels of this system.

[image: Energy levels]

Here is a diagram of the energy levels. According to my book, each of the final levels, have a degeneracy of $2j+1$ due to the values of $m_j$. Hence the total degeneracy of the state comes to be $60$. However, I'm facing a huge confusion regarding this.

If we look at the spin-spin interaction, we find the energy split into singlets and triplets. Let us look at the triplet state $^{3}P$ for example. It has been further split into 3 levels, due to different values of $J$, and then into more levels due to values of $m_j$. However, I don't seem to understand, why are we ignoring $m_s$ in here. Before even considering $J$, shouldn't $^3P$ be split into $^3P(m_s=-1)$ ,$ ^3P(m_s=-0)$ and $^3P(m_s=1)$, and then each of these states be further divided based on different values of $J$ ? Is $m_s$ a 'bad' quantum number in this scenario? If so, then why? Moreover, why are we not taking into account, the degeneracy due to $m_l$? Shouldn't the total no. of states, exceed 60?

Why are we ignoring the degeneracy due to spin-spin interaction? According to Wikipedia, **spin-multiplicity** represents the number of possible states of J for a given L and S, provided that L ≥ S. However I don't see how that is true. Mathematically it seems to work, as I'd expect to see $3$ different states due to $m_s$, and I do get to see exactly $3$ different states, but due to $J$ instead. There may be a connection here that I'm failing to see. Is there some connection between $m_s$ and $J$?

Yes, we are getting a triplet for $^3P$, in the above diagram, but that is due to **spin-orbit interaction**. Shouldn't we get a separate triplet for the **spin-spin interaction** ? Are the two triplets one and the same?

Shouldn't the $^3P$ level, look more like this : [image]

In the diagram, the three $m_s$ states should be side by side, as energy doesn't depend on that, but if we are talking about the total no. of states, instead of $3$ states due to different values of $J$, shouldn't there be $9$ as shown by the picture ?

I seem to be extremely confused about the entire thing. if anyone can explain this to me coherently, that would be much appreciated. Why do we ignore $m_s$,$m_l$ and the degenracy associated with them, and take into account only $m_j$. Also, how does spin multiplicity, gives the no. of degenerate staes due to values of $J$ ? Shouldn't it give us the degenracy due to values of $m_s$ ?

**EDIT:**

Based on some further reading, I'm lead to believe, that I'm mixing between two alternate descriptions of the same eigenstate. There are two ways to describe the eigenstate,

(i) $|S,L,m_l,m_s \rangle$ and (ii) $|S,L,J,m_j \rangle$.

I was probably butchering the entire concept, and trying to create an eigenstate $|S,L,J,m_l,m_s \rangle$, not realizing that I'm double-counting, when I'm counting $m_s,m_l$ and $J$ separately.

However, I'm still not sure how the two representations are connected. For example, in the first representation, we retain information about the z-component of the electrons' spin and angular momentum. However, in the second representation, we only know the z-component of total angular momentum.  How are these two representations equivalent, and how does spin multiplicity tell us the no. of possible values because of $J$.

An explanation would be most welcome.

How do we connect the two representations. For example, we have $|S,L,m_l,m_s \rangle = |1,1,0,-1 \rangle$. Let this exact state in the second representation be $|1,1,J,m_j \rangle$. How will we know which exact value of $J$and $m_j$ represent this exact state ?

Comment: Decomposing a $\left | S, L, m_l, m_s \right >$ state into $\left | S, L, J, m_j \right >$ states is exactly the problem of computing Clebsch-Gordan coefficients.

Comment: @ConnorBehan shouldn't there be a one-to-one correspondence, as there are the same no. of uncoupled basis states and terms?

Comment: If by one-to-one correspondence you mean change of basis, then yes. The Clebsch-Gordan coefficients are the entries in the change of basis matrix.